# Google Apps Scripts - Accessing Cell Notes and Comments

Tags: google-apps-script, cell, google-sheets

Hello everybody and thank you for taking the time to check out my question. I am a 9th grade teacher making a customized grade sheet and just finished a GUI that lets parents see their kid's grades. However, on the actual gradesheet I use cell notes (previously, comments) to store information specific to a grade (i.e. Jimmy was missing part b of the assignment). I would like to be able to access the data within those notes.

I would like to consider myself a good researcher but have not been able to find a single reference to apps scripts interacting with cell comments or notes. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, should there be no infrastructure to support this, I am very open to other ideas on how to store related information while still keeping my interface more more or less constant.

my interface: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuptsBCDJBomdGtjc0xBcDctZ3FENmlsdlpRQmdkNkE

parent interface is a simple form that takes a student id number and returns a flex table with grade headers and only that students information.

Comment: I hope all the spreadsheet's names, emails, phone numbers, etc. are fake. They are public.

Comment: Same comment from me ! I hope these are fakes...

Comment: Here's an SO question explaining how to get notes in 2019. Comments are still not possible to be interacted with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609953/get-cell-note-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Range.getComments() method to gain access to the comments on cells.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#getComment

---

Update (original author: [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730189/simon)):

Google Docs Comments were relaunched on Sept 5th 2012 as discussion-style comments. All the old Comments were renamed to be Notes. See [this notice](https://cloud.googleblog.com/2012/09/google-spreadsheets-now-with-discussions.html). The curious thing is that Google has kept the old simple Notes, but not provided any documentation for it.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how that escaped me. Do you know if it is also possible for notes? The new type of comments are less useful for my purpose.

Comment: Well, the notes features is pretty new to Google Spreadsheets. Generally, Apps Scripts functions trail the UI whenever new features are released. Even very simple methods such as getDescription() and setDescription() were added recently. You can, however, add an enhancement request in the issue tracker to be notified when it is added to Apps Scripts

Comment: Actually, it turns out that getComments() retrieves what are now called "notes". Interesting, and frustrating.

Comment: There is no getComment method in Class Range now. Only getNote. :(