# Get Sheet cell note value with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to [get the value of a cell note](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnote) and display it in the cell next to it?

I have a column C where some of the cells contain notes. I would like to get these note values and write each cell note in the cell next to it in column D.

For example: if cell C4 has a note "No entry", I want to display "No entry" in D4.

Answer (score 16):

I needed to do this today and found your question but no answer.  This is what I finally came up with. You can do this by setting up a function in the script editor named getNote.

```
function getNote(cell)
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var range = ss.getRange(cell)
   return range.getNote();
}
```

then in your spreadsheet enter:

```
=getNote("C4")
```

to get the note from cell C4.  If you want it to be a reference that changes when you move around the cells, then reference it this way:

```
=getNote(Address(row(C4), column(C4)))
```

**Word of caution**: Notes don't trigger a refresh, so if a note is edited the cell does not pick up the new value right away

Comment: Word of caution:  Notes don't trigger a refresh, so if a note is edited the cell does not pick up the new value right away.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Whether I specify the cell address as a string or using `Address()` doesn't matter, the function appears to return nothing. I temporarily altered the function a little (`return "fubar"`) to ensure it is executing.  (It does.)   Will it make a difference if the spreadsheet from which the function is called has multiple sheets?

Comment: for those interested, there is also a `getNotes` if you're working on a range of cells

Comment: If used on a mouse selected cell, the input syntax is `=getNote(C4)` without the quotes. Is it possible to adapt the script to work on that too?

Comment: This worked for me when i added the quotes around the cell number. =getNote("H35")

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the script to fetch a range instead of a singular cell. In the script, substitute`cell` with `range`. Then in the sheet you can specify the range with formula `=getnotes("J:J")`. This will return the entire range of cells that contain notes.