# Permission to Call SpreadsheetApp.OpenById()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Here is the problem, i need to read the note from a external spreadsheet, so recently i search and found this anwser: [Get cell note value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609953/get-cell-note-value) but it isn't working with external spreadsheets, i tried a lot of things, but nothing worked, somebody can help me?

Sheet A - Example

[image: Sheet A - Example]

Sheet B - Getting value (ImportRange) - Request

[image: Sheet B - Getting value (ImportRange) - Request]

Sheet B - Getting value (ImportRange) - Return

[image: Sheet B - Getting value (ImportRange) - Return]

Sheet B - Getting Notes(Custom Script) - Request FAIL

[image: Sheet B - Getting Notes(Custom Script) - Request FAIL]

```
function getNote2(cell, token)
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(token)
   var range = ss.getRange(cell)
   return range.getNote();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You do not have permission to call openById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587331/you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-openbyid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) specifies:

> Spreadsheet
> Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()).
> **Cannot open other spreadsheets** (SpreadsheetApp.openById() or
> SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()).

### **So unfortunately you will need to come up with another solution**

Possible solutions would be

- running the script from the Apps Script editor whereby the values
- Importing the script as a custom macro

[image]

- Create a button and [assign the script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) to it

**In any case you will need to slightly rewrite your script**

- Instead of `return` you will need to use the method [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) to set the note into the cell of choice (e.g. the active cell)

**Sample script**

```js
function callMe(){
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var cellWithNotes = "A4";
  var id = "PASTE HERE THE SPREADSHEET ID";
  var note = getNote(cellWithNotes, id);
  activeCell.setValue(note);
}


function getNote(cell, token)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(token)
  var range = ss.getRange(cell)
  return range.getNote();
}
```

- Run the function `callMe()` either manually or in another way as described above
- Instead of hardcoding the `cellReference` and `id` you can retrieve them dynamically e.g. from a table - depending on your situation

Comment: Thanks bro! it Worked! i Really appreciate your help!